# CaliburnMicro attaching message to buttons in AppBar not works at first time

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, caliburn.micro

I have ShellView which is conductor. It contains StartView, where I create Appbar. But there is a lot of another views in my application and appbar looks similar on all screens so I have made AppBarView and AppBarViewModel.
My AppBar defined like this:

```
***StartView***

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="BottomAppBar">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
            <local:AppBarView Caliburn:Bind.Model="{Binding AppBarViewModel}" />
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

***AppBarView***

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Name="Play"  Style="{StaticResource PlayAppBarButtonStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I also create AppBarViewModel with method `Play` (It's by CM conventions).

When i run application and open AppBar first time my button not works. But if I hide and open again AppBar - all works great.

Any ideas why it not works at first time?
Thank you!

**UPD:**
There is error in output window in debug:

`Error: BindingExpression path error: 'AppBarViewModel' property not found on 'MusicMaker.ViewModels.AppBarViewModel, MusicMaker, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='AppBarViewModel' DataItem='MusicMaker.ViewModels.AppBarViewModel, MusicMaker, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'MusicMaker.Views.AppBarView' (Name='null'); target property is 'Model' (type 'Object')`

Comment: Are **StartView** and **AppBarView** defined in different XAML files ?

Comment: Yes. It's defferent files. And StartViewModel contains AppBarViewModel.

Comment: Are you getting any Binding errors in the output console when running the application in debug mode inside Visual Studio, and is AppBarViewModel you are using in binding defined as property on StartViewModel ?

Comment: @Sniffer thank you! Yes, there is an error. Please see update for question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions for you Alexei but they may not work but at least you can try:

1. Replace `Caliburn:Bind.Model="{Binding AppBarViewModel}"` with `Caliburn:View.Model="{Binding AppBarViewModel}"`.
2. If the first option doesn't work then check out this [Screens, Conductors and Composition article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/10/08/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-6a-screens-conductors-and-composition.aspx) to see how the author did View-First, pay attention that he used a string instead of a binding markup inside `Caliburn:Bind.Model="{Binding AppBarViewModel}"`.

That is all i can say. Hope it helps.